# How to loop over sequence with variable in Twig?

Tags: for-loop, twig

According to [Twig's documentation on the "for" tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html), the `..` operator can be used to iterate over a sequence of numbers:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to use a variable that stores the upper bound, instead of a hard-coded number? e.g.,

```
{% set max = 10 %}
...
{% for i in 0..{{ max }} %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I try the above code, I get this error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the variable like this

```
{% set max = 10 %}
...
{% for i in 0..max %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

[playground example](https://twigfiddle.com/tbgkf2)

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks. I don't know how I missed that!